# SonarQube 6.7: How can a enable/see group level summary for SQ report

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

How can I see the summary of all projects in sonarQube 6.7? Can we enable the user-level view of SQ 6.7? For example, as a developer, i want to see all detail but as manager, i would like to see the team level or group level summary or analysis (bugs, issues, coverage progress).

Comment: The use cases you're describing sounds very close to what the Enterprise Edition provided by SonarSource is providing (see Governance Benefits).
You'll find everything about it on https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/.

Comment: You can also try to use the SonarQube API and build your own summary.

Comment: Is there any free plug-in available which is equivalent to Governance plug-in?

Comment: The required APIs are not available in SonarQube 6.7. https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2752802  https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392181